# How can I reject a string containing non-consecutive characters in a date format

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to come up with a regex which will reject non-consecutive characters in a supplied date format.  I want to be as flexible as possible, and so I have decided that my date format string can contain YY or YYYY, MM or MMM, DD or DDD, hh mm and ss.

Some of the regex I have worked out already - for example, matching the following will show that the month is a 3 character format:

`([M])\1{2}`

I'm totally in the dark with regard to checking that the date format doesn't contain non consecutive characters.  For example, the following date formats should be valid:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
hh:mm:ss YYYY-MM-DD 
DD/MMM/YYYYhh-mm
```

But these formats should be rejected

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss YYYY // year appears twice
hh:mm:ss YYYY-MM-DD hh // hour appears twice
DD/MMM/YYYYhh-mm m // m not consecutive with other m
```

In the interests of future expansion, I want to allow non consecutive special characters (/ - . : ) etc and reject all non-consecutive alpha-numeric characters.  Case sensitive though - mm and MM are not not the same (as above)

Just to be clear - I'm not trying to validate an actual date - I am trying to validate a date format string only.

Comment: Wouldnt it be simpler to pre-parse the input before regex? Then you could have the same quantifier on each field year, month, day.

Comment: Sounds like one of those problems that should rather not be attempted to be solved by regex alone in the first place. Especially when you need to start that kind of “counting”, to prevent parts to occur more than once - that should be a pretty strong indicator IMHO, that you should not try to cram the whole thing purely into a regular expression to begin with.

Comment: Try `/(\w)\1*(?!\1).*\1/`, e.g.  `function(text) { return !/(\w)\1*(?!\1).*\1/.test(text); }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - put this as an answer please.  That appears to work.  You are a regex ninja!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking if there is at least one occurrence of the same character that has already been present before, and then negating the outcome:

```
function(text) { 
    return !/(\w)\1*(?!\1).*\1/.test(text);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzKv3Z/1). You may change `\w` to `[YMDhms]` to only check these six letters.

**Pattern details**

- `(\w)` - Group 1 (further referenced to with the `\1` backreference): a word char
- `\1*` - zero or more occurrences of the same char as in Group 1
- `(?!\1)` - set a boundary, make sure there next char is not the same as the char in Group 1
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\1` - the same char as in Group 1.

Comment: what happens in this case? `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss X`  or to OP will this be a scenario?

Comment: @JBone You may test it yourself using my regex fiddle, it [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/wzKv3Z/2). Whether it is expected or not, let OP decide.

Comment: I agree with `\w` it will work but if you replace `\w` with `[YMDhms]` it does not work

Comment: @JBone Then add `Xx` to the character class. It is customizable.

Comment: Even with that your `\1` will be `Y` but at the end you encountered `X`. is't it?

Comment: @JBone It looks like you have a different problem. Feel free to post a separate question.